# Return error message when Post JSON is incorrect

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, post

I need to *validate a *JSON** before saving the information on the database. The object has the following pattern:

```
{
   "id": "string",
   "name": "string",
   "description": "string",
   "price": "int"
}
```

If the post was made with the correct *JSON*, I return the object saved (The ID can't be in the post, it will be generated by database).

But, if the post has a missing field or additional one I need to return an error message.

How is the best way to do this? I'm reading some articles and can't understand exactly.

I'm using spring-boot, *JPA*, connecting to an *H2 database (MVC Pattern)*.

Here is my Controller and Service layer:

First, the delete method. That works as I want.

```
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity<Product> deleteProduct(@PathVariable String id) {
        ResponseEntity<Product> response = productService.deleteProduct(id);
        return response;
    }

    public ResponseEntity<Product> deleteProduct(String id) {
        Optional<Product> product = productRepository.findById(id);
        if (product.isPresent()) {
            productRepository.deleteById(id);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
        } else
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
```

Here the Post Method. That I can't find a good way to return the response that I want:

```
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Product> insertProduct(@RequestBody ProductForm form) {
        Product product = productService.insertProduct(form);
        if (product) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(product);
        } else
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }

    public Product insertProduct(ProductForm form) {
        Product product = form.insertConverter();
        productRepository.save(product);
        return product;
    }
```

The second method in both snippets is located in a separated JavaClass.

This was what I want to return:

```
  {
    "code": integer,
    "error": "string"
  }
```

Comment: I think you don't have to do that as spring will send a 400 bad request if body doesn't match dto object.

Comment: I need to return a JSON as reponse. And I don't know why, but the response comes as 500 (internal server error). I will edit and post my controller and service layer

Comment: You can look into ControllerAdvice that catches an exception and delivers back the error with a custom model https://www.baeldung.com/global-error-handler-in-a-spring-rest-api